# How to get rid of "mixi.dj search" engine in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, spyware, search-engines

Every time I restart Google Chrome, the defalt search engine is set to "mixi.DJ search", even if I remove it from the list of search engines.

How to definitively get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a search engine hijack. Chrome 25 is adding two new features to prevent silent extension installs. From the [Chrome blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html):

> Extensions installed by third party programs using external extension
>   deployment options will be disabled by default. When a third party
>   program installs an extension, the Chrome menu will be badged, and
>   users can click through the Chrome menu to see a dialog containing an
>   option to enable the extension or to remove it from their computer.
>
> In addition, all extensions previously installed using external
>   deployment options will be automatically disabled. Chrome will show a
>   one-time prompt to allow the re-enabling of any of the extensions.

I don't know if this will block all search engine hijacks but it will go a long way to stopping a lot of them.

Steps to remove now that it is there:

- If you haven't upgraded to the latest version of Chrome do that first.
- Check your installed programs and remove anything you don'r recognize.
- Download an anti-spyware program and run that.
- Disable any Chrome extensions you don't recognize
- Remove the search engine and set the default back to Chrome.

Comment: I would like to add a point to @Brand Patton. There is also possibility that a software which you have installed recently have installed . If that is the case please log in safe mode during boot time so that the program doesn't initialize itself during the start, follow above steps whichhe has mentioned .